# Dropped Parse.com installation table ,returns error Object not found in .NET win8 store apps

Tags: windows-store-apps, parse-platform

i dropped my installation class and recreated again and now i get error in saveasync line.

```
 protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var parseinstallation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;

    await parseinstallation.SaveAsync();
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is uninstall your app from your OS and launch it again through visual studio.It worked because it was using the cached data .

Answer (score 0):

If reinstallation is not an option, you should also be able to update your app so that is saves your local installation data in a backup table.

From there you can take the data and place it in new entries in the installation table.

I described the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24818276/1057968) for iOS. But maybe it helps here, too.