# How to recreate deleted installation table at parse.com

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I accidentally dropped the `Installation` table in the parse.com data browser.

This table contained device data of my iOS users. With the **device ID´s missing**, i **can´t send** the users any **push notifications**.

The only way I know to recreate a installation row is to delete and **reinstall the app**. But this is **no option** because it totally breaks the user experience.

Is there a way to recreate the rows of the installations table from the objective C code?

Or anyway access the installationID and deviceToken, in that case so I would recreate the table per hand.

Comment: Please edit question mentioning more relevant info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As all [other methods](https://www.parse.com/questions/remove-cached-parse-installation-from-android-device) did not work, i updated my app in a way that saves all data of the `currentInstallation` in a backup table.

```
PFObject *backupInstallation = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"installationRecovery"];
for (NSString *key in [PFInstallation currentInstallation].allKeys) {
    // Filter out the basic keys.
    if (![@[@"objectId", @"createdAt", @"updatedAt"] containsObject:key]) {
        [backupInstallation setObject:[PFInstallation currentInstallation][key] forKey:key];
    }
}
[backupInstallation saveInBackground];
```

After i got all installation entries, i manually added the missing ones to the `Installation` table. Although the `objectId`´s did not match the ones in the local entries, i got the push notifications to work.

You can also handle the copy job by writing a cloud function that does it for you. This could be triggered in a post save hook of `installationRecovery`.

I also made shure that this code only executes once on update. By checking a user default setting.

```
NSString *backuppedInstallation = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"backuppedInstallation"];
if (!backuppedInstallation) {
    // Your code here
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:@(YES) forKey:@"backuppedInstallation"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```